Ceiling light fixture bracket
I am trying to replace the existing light with a new led flush mount. The junction box looks really big (6.5in) and it doesn’t have any holes in straight opposite direction to screw in the mounting brackets. I am having trouble finding the mounting brackets here. Appreciate any solution on how to mount the led light here.
It looks something like this .

Added a picture. *This had a link attached to it.

That's not a junction box, that's the old recessed can light fixture.  You'll need to remove the old fixture and install the new one in it's place.

what was in there before

Old recessed ceiling light with spring clips. That appears to be the only option it could mount.

Got a pic of your new light?

You need to remove the Can.
Remove the wing nut holding the upper plate and remove the plate. Then remove the can. It can be done by removing three 1/4" hex head screws. ( blue line).
The can then may be pushed up into the attic or pulled down out of the holder.
This gives axcess to the wiring box, where you can get to the cable providing power. (Be sure the power is off).
From there you will have to fabricate a mounting brace and install the necessary 4 inch metal double gang box.  This is what you can mount the bar on for the new light.
You should consider adding some dead wood to repair the drywall on the ceiling.


Thank you. I think I am not capable of doing that myself. Most of the latest recessed light comes with bulb socket to be screwed in, but I don’t see that option here. Is there any way to just change the existing light with regular recessed led light since I don’t have a socket? Can I add a light built adapter to this one and would that work?

@ayim, that's really a whole new question and you would need to show us a pic of the "guts" of the can. Most of the time, though, old school can lights had a standard socket into which you would screw the bulb. They make LED flood and spot lights that will screw into standard sockets, and they make replacement "puck" lights that will screw into them as well. If you never had a socket here, it must have been removed by a previous occupant. They are replaceable, though it might be hard to find the exact one for this can - you may have to pull another one then go to an electrical supply house.

... to ask their help in identifying a suitable replacement. Wire the replacement socket into this can then put in your new LED bulb/puck
